# Modelling motion of a balloon that is decreasing in volume

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to find the function for velocity of a balloon that is decreasing in volume in free fall.

My balloon is half sphere, half ellipsoid. Its volume equation is given by:

$$V = \frac{2 \pi}{3} r^3 + \frac{2 \pi b r^2}{3}$$

My function for velocity is:

$$v(t)=\sqrt{\frac{2mg}{\rho C_{d} A}}\tanh\left(t\sqrt{\frac{\rho C_{d} A g}{2m}}\right)$$

Where

$$A=\pi r^2$$

I have decided that the volume will decrease at an exponential rate:

$$- \frac{dV}{dt} = e^{-t+k}$$

I have also decided that $\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{dr}{dt}$.

Is there anyway to find this velocity function? How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: How thorough do you want this? I think the drag will probably be stronger than the buoyancy so the expression needs to address both. Mass conservation means the mass of the balloon is decreasing over time with shrinking volume.  Unless the leaking gas is uniform it contributes to the motion. You'll need to solve something like $m(t)\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}=-m(t)g-b(t)\frac{dz}{dt}+\rho g V(t)$

Comment: "I have also decided that $\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dt}$." I don't see how this "decision" can be useful.

Comment: At some point, you need to introduce some actual physics to relate the volume of the balloon and its velocity. The Tsiolkovsky rocket equation seems appropriate then you can relate the change in mass of the balloon to the change in volume via the density of air.